# how to make foreman start god

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, foreman, god

I have a Procfile like this:

```
web: bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E production
god: god -c services.god
```

but `foreman start god` doesn't start...it's just say this:

```
17:14:32 god.1  | started with pid 29506
17:14:32 god.1  | exited with code 0
17:14:32 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

if I run `god -c services.god`, all services run fine...
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be running god with foreman. foreman is used to specify all the background (and web) processes in your application, and god is a process monitoring framework for those processes.

Typically, you should:

1. Specify all your processes directly in your `Procfile` (instead of `services.god`), and use `foreman start` to run them in development.
2. Use god to monitor the processes in production. I use my [foreman_god](https://github.com/embarkmobile/foreman_god) gem to load the Procfile directly with god. Alternatively, you can [export a god config file](https://github.com/otherinbox/foreman-export-god/).

---

That said, if you really want to run god from foreman: god runs as a daemon by default, and daemons don't work with foreman (see [this wiki page](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/wiki/Process-immediately-terminating)). It should work if you pass the -D (Don't daemonize) option to god:

```
god: god -D -c services.god
```

Answer (score 1):

may be you should use something like this if you are using god with rvm,

```
god: rvmsudo god -c /path_to_yourgod_file.god
```

but why you need two different monitoring systems while you can use any one them to get your work done?

Comment: I'm not using rvm anymore...what do you mean 'two different monitoring systems'?